# Launching an ActivityForResult from Activity A with createChooser Intent I want to finish Activity A but not when the user presses the back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, share, activity-finish

So I have this in Activity A:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share using"), 0);
```

which launches a chooser to share something using Activity B.  When Activity B finishes I want Activity A to also finish so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    this.finish();

}
```

The problem is that when the user presses the back button when the chooser is open, Activity A finishes... which I don't want to happen.  I have tried overwriting the onBackPressed method in Activity A but this seemingly does not apply when the chooser is open.  Please help me.

Update: I should mention Activity B is not under my control and is whatever the user decides to share with.

Update 2: The problem is that the chooser activity and the activity that is chosen from the chooser by the user is considered the same activity so that when the user closes Activity B (the one used to share the text) onActivityResult gets the same resultCode and the same requestCode as it does from the chooser activity.  There has to be a way around this but I can't think of it.

Comment: remove `this.finish()` from your method.

Comment: Why? I want Activity A to finish when Activity B finishes.

Comment: method si called when intent finished from your code i don't know, which type of intent/action you want to do, you created intent like createChooser so when chooser is closed, method onAcivityResult is called and your Activity A also. so this approach is not right.

Comment: I did not. I ended up just using startActivity(). Not the exact behavior I wanted but not too big of a deal... at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You should test what return requestCode and resultCode before calling

`this.finish();`

This way, if the user press back button before choosing something, your activity A will not be destroyed.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work because the values of requestCode and resultCode are the same when the user presses the back button and when the user finishes Activity B.  I should mention Activity B is not under my control and is whatever the user decides to share with.

Comment: The resultCode is the way provided by the system to handle the situation. The chooser should return to you RESULT_CANCELED if the user bailed before picking. If other applications beyond your control are returning RESULT_CANCELED to you when they actually succeeded (e.g. RESULT_OK) then I don't think there is much that you are going to be able to do. But I think for the most part checking the resultCode with an if statement is going to be how you want to solve the situation. Can you give specific examples where you have observed it not behave in the normal manner? (i.e. returns incorrect code)

Comment: The only incorrect behavior occurs when the user presses the back button with the chooser open (Activity A finishes when I don't want it to).  Since Activity B is not under my control I have no idea what resultCode it returns.  From testing I know that, for example if I share using the Facebook or Twitter app and then close the app, the resultCode is 0.  This is understandable since the developers of those apps decided to send out no resultCode when the app shares something or finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that it is **a)** The correct activity and **b)** the correct result code.  Your onActivityResult should look something like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```